# tbody css styling lost when replaced

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I'm trying to sort the table and when the replace the sorted tbody, i lose the css styling.

```
<table id= "pcaHistory" class="pcaTransactionsTable claim-list-table" style="margin-left: 0px">
<tbody><tr class="top-row bottom-row" style="cursor: default">
    <td class="date-cell">{{transactionDate}}</td>
    <td class="transaction-cell">{{type}}</td>
    <td class="transaction-cell">{{icn}}</td>
    <td class="balance-before-cell">{{balanceBeforeTransaction}}</td>
    <td class="amount-cell">{{amount}}</td>
    <td class="balance-after-cell">{{balanceAfterTransaction}}</td>
</tr>
```

In the js, I'm using the following -

```
   var $tbody = $('#pcaHistory tbody');
    var $tbody = $tbody.find('tr').sort(function(a,b){
                    var tda = $(a).find('.date-cell').text();
                    var tdb = $(b).find('.date-cell').text();
                    // if a < b return 1

                    if(SORT === 0)
                        return new Date(tda) - new Date(tdb);
                    else
                        return new Date(tdb) - new Date(tda);
                });
    $('#pcaHistory tbody').replaceWith($tbody);
```

When i do this, it lose the css styling that comes from `class=claim-list-table`

css

```
.claim-list-table {    
    tbody {
        border-bottom: 1px solid @gray;
    }
```

How do I fix this ?

Comment: Why are you replacing an element with itself? Does `----Sorting logic----` set `$tbody` to a new element?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'm guessing that dharag is just omitting the sorting logic from the code so that it's easier to read.

Comment: var $tbody contains all the rows in the sorted way after the sorting logic is done. I dont have problems sorting or displaying the rows when I do the replace. But it doesnt use the same styling though.

Comment: I think the $tbody var after sorting contains only the <tr> tags and not the <tbody> , so when I do replaceWith, the tbody styling gets lost.

Comment: @dharag, that's exactly it. Don't assign to `$tbody` the second time. You do not need to. Also remove your call to `replaceWith()`, you don't need it either.